# Xcode not Importing Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

I have installed the SDK and when I did the

Import Firbase

then continued my project to add FIRAuth.auth it did not come up and neither are other commands.

Comment: Voting to close, no explanation of how you installed the Firebase SDK, no version of Firebase SDK you are using

Comment: Latest version of  Firebase SDK is Import Firebase and Auth.auth() in Swift by the way

Answer (score 2):

While you haven't given us much to work with, I'll give this a shot.

Firstly, I would follow [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) which describes how to install it. I will also detail it here.

You will need to install [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/)

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

1. Create a Firebase project in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), if you don't already have one. If you already have an existing Google project associated with your mobile app, click **Import Google Project**. Otherwise, click **Create New Project**.
2. Click Add Firebase to your iOS app and follow the setup steps. If you're importing an existing Google project, this may happen automatically and you can just [download the config file](http://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592).
3. When prompted, enter your app's bundle ID. It's important to enter the bundle ID your app is using; this can only be set when you add an app to your Firebase project.
4. At the end, you'll download a GoogleService-Info.plist file. You can [download this file again](http://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) at any time.
5. If you haven't done so already, copy this into your Xcode project root.

**ADDING THE SDK**

Open the terminal and CD to your project directory.

Type `pod init`, then `nano Podfile`

Add `pod 'Firebase/Core'` before `end`

Then `CTRL + X, y, Enter`

Now type `pod install`

Then, `open your-project.xcworkspace` (Important to open the `xcworkspace` and not the other)

And finally, Download a GoogleService-Info.plist file from [Firebase console and include it in your app.

Yay!

Now in your app

`import Firebase`

Comment: "If this helped you, please consider accepting the answer."  Really?

Comment: Yeah really, not because I'm begging for it, but because based on the quality of the question, it would seem the user is relatively new to SO. So they might not know when you should upvote, downvote, and accept answers. I didn't mean to come off as beggy

Comment: @Will Nice answer! In general coaxing a user to upvote or accept your answer is discouraged on Stack Overflow. If you think this user doesn't grok SO yet (I typically wait for proof of that, before assuming it based on their rep), leave a comment. Also see this great discussion on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it